# «convencer» pode significar tentar convencer?

Tags: significado, verbos

Outro dia alguém me disse algo assim:

> Quando eu sair de lá, eles vão convencer-me a ficar. Vão convencer-me sim.

Mas no contexto, ficou claro que estava a dizer que **eles vão tentar, mas não vão conseguir.** Fiquei surpreendido com isto, porque no meu entender, *convencer* (transitivo) era sinónimo de *conseguir convencer* e não podia ser sinónimo de *tentar convencer*. Fui para os dicionários, e acho que todos os que consultei dizem que *convencer* fala dum sucesso, não duma tentativa. Dizem que *convencer* neste uso significa *persuadir*, e que *persuadir* significa

> Levar ou levar-se a acreditar ou a executar alguma coisa
>
> <sub>"persuadir", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, http://priberam.pt/dlpo/persuadir [consultado em 08-06-2016].</sub>

E para mim, *persuadir* e *levar a executar* não parecem admitir um significado de *tentar*. Mas estou ciente que posso estar a confundir alguma coisa.

O verbo *convencer* pode significar *tentar convencer* ou não? É a mesma coisa com *persuadir* e *levar a fazer*?

Comment: Assim sem consultar nada eu diria que não é a mesma coisa. Eu naquele caso diria *Quando eu sair de lá, eles vão tentar convencer-me a ficar. Vão tentar convencer-me sim.* se quisesse passar a ideia que vão tentar.

Comment: É um uso que também já encontrei, e também me causa muita confusão.

Comment: Acho que é um uso não-padrão. Se me eu te disser *convence-o*, subentende-se *tenta convencê-lo*, porque convencê-lo de facto pode não estar no teu poder. Mas doutro modo *convencer* não é *tentar convencer*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eles vão

- **tentar**
- **querer**
- **se esforçar para**
- **fazer tudo para**  ...............me convencer.

Em pt-BR, todas as opções acima têm o significado literal.  Da mesma forma, **"eles vão me convencer"** também tem significado literal. Entretanto, isso não impede que alguém use "vão me convencer" com o sentido de "vão tentar me convencer", mas não é uso corrente e pode soar ambíguo.  O mesmo se aplica a "persuadir" e "levar a fazer".

Comment: Em pt-BR "Quando eu sair de lá, eles vão me convencer a ficar. Vão me convencer sim!" A pessoa está certa que será convencida, e por isso, é uma certeza que a tentativa de convencimento é positiva. Por isso não se usa o 'tentar', mas uma frase acessória "vão me convencer sim".

Comment: Mas @AndréLyra, a pessoa está certa que **não** será convencida! A pergunta é toda acerca disso. No corpo da pergunta está até escrito que «no contexto, ficou claro que estava a dizer que *eles vão tentar, mas não vão conseguir*.»

Comment: Sem o contexto eu entendo que ela precisa sair, mas vai ser convencida a ficar. Assim como uma pessoa que gosta de uma boa festa é convencida a ficar mesmo tendo de ir trabalhar cedo no outro dia.